# adding/copy objects to a new list in java

Tags: java

I want to copy objects in a list to a new list if they pass a condition.

I have an arraylist called "inschrijvingen", in this array list there are objects of "Speler".

If the object passes this methtod with true:

```
/**
     *
     * @param speler
     * @return
     */
    private boolean magDeelnemen(Speler speler) {
        Collections.sort(inschrijving);
        return speler.getHandicap() <= minNiveau && inschrijving.size() < maxSpelers;
    }
```

I want to copy it to a new arraylist called "spelers"
I've written this method for it:

```
/**
     * Als de deadline voor inschrijven is aangekomen kan de organisatie kijken wie mee mag spelen
     */
    public void isSpeler() {
        for (Speler speler : this.inschrijving) {
            if (magDeelnemen(speler)) {
                this.spelers.add(speler);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to have the objects in both arraylist, but when I run this code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Collections.sort(inschrijving)` from `magDeelnemen`.
If you need to sort the list `inschrijving`, sort it before or after the isSpeller's loop. In your case, you modify the list on iteration, thats why exception is rased and you do a sort on every iteration, which is waste the cpu cycles.
Also, you can use stream to create the same behaviour:

```
 this.inschrijving.stream().sorted().filter(this::magDeelnemen).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input, when i try the stream in de isSpeler() method I get "cannot resolve method sorted in list.

Comment: Try call stream() on list before sorted

Comment: No errors now thanks, but now it says on .collect "resuslt of stream.collect is ignored"

Comment: The result is the list you want so assign it to a variable

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through`this.inschrijving` and calling the method `magDeelnemen` within the loop. But within that method you're sorting the `inschrijving`.

You can't modify the collection you're looping through, and I don't see why it would have to be sorted in that method, so the best solution is just to remove that `Collection.sort(inschrijving)`

Comment: Not remove but replace from magDeelnemen to first string in isSpeler(),

Comment: Thanks! yes I put the collection.sort in the wrong method, thanks for seeing it!